# Use Find-Replace to wrap strings that start and end with the same characters

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

Using Notepad++, this is to wrap HTML `<img ... />` tags with `<p>` tags, but each full `<img ... />` string contains different characters.

What I want to do is use Notepad++ "Find" tool to find each `<img ... />` tag, then use "Replace" to wrap each `<img ... />` with `<p></p>` tags.

This is to wrap the `<img>` tags faster than manually doing it.

Example:

Find...

```
<img src="https://example.com/image-icon-9.jpg" alt="text here" class="alignleft size-full" title="test-here" width="50" height="50" />
<img src="https://example.com/image-icon-12.jpg" alt="text here" class="alignleft size-full" title="test-here" width="50" height="50" />
<img src="https://example.com/image-icon-5.jpg" alt="text here" class="alignleft size-full" title="test-here" width="50" height="50" />
<img src="https://example.com/image-icon-8.jpg" alt="text here" class="alignleft size-full" title="test-here" width="50" height="50" />
```

Replace by wrapping the `<img ... />` tags with `<p>` tags

```
<p><img src="https://example.com/image-icon-9.jpg" alt="text here" class="alignleft size-full" title="test-here" width="50" height="50" /></p>
<p><img src="https://example.com/image-icon-12.jpg" alt="text here" class="alignleft size-full" title="test-here" width="50" height="50" /></p>
<p><img src="https://example.com/image-icon-5.jpg" alt="text here" class="alignleft size-full" title="test-here" width="50" height="50" /></p>
<p><img src="https://example.com/image-icon-8.jpg" alt="text here" class="alignleft size-full" title="test-here" width="50" height="50" /></p>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    <img.*?/>
Replace: <p>$0</p>
```

### Demo

Comment: I forgot to add, when using this method above, in the Notepad++ "Find - Replace", ensure the: 
"Regular expression" is selected (and...)
".matches newline" is unchecked.